# Active Directory GPO not working with Windows XP clients. Work fine with Windows 7

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

We have 2008 Enterprise R2 64 bit domain controller with Windows XP and Windows 7 as clients. When i try to use a group policy to make all users desktop wallpaper to a common JPG image    ( Image is shared in server with every one have read permission on it ). The policy works fine with Win 7. But in Win XP the background is white. The desired background comes for a while at the time of log in and log off then it's became white.

I tried many ways and it's not working. Like force updating the policy with "gpupdate /force " command in both server and client. Stll the same. Please help me to sort out this issue

Comment: Do you have the Group Policy Preferences Client Side Extensions installed on the WinXP machines?

Answer (score -1):

Yesterday i put the question regarding the issue that i found with applying GPO in my domain for common centralized desktop background. Today i found one fare solution for that. And i would like to post it.

What i done is that just remove my XP clients membership from the domain and try to rejoin to the domain. That's all. The issue getting resolved. The method is not suitable if you have large number of XP clients. Because you have to go to each XP client to make this change.

Notice that if you remove the domain membership then you have to log in with local user credentials. So be aware about our local user name and password. If you don't know, the situation will be panic. Then you have to use some kind of XP password setting utility to reset it again.